# Setting custom view to UIViewController's view displays a blank view with a constraint warning: "Position and size are ambiguous for {my base view}"

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom base view that I want to set to my subclassed `UIViewController`'s `view` property programmatically (NO auto-layout).

The following code does not display anything (black screen when the view controller is pushed onto the stack) and when I go to debug the view hierarchy, it shows a warning on said base view that says:

> "Position and size are ambiguous for BaseView"

Below is the most dumbed-down version of my code that produces this warning and lack of display:

My custom base view:

```
class BaseView: UIView {

    // Subviews

    private var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    // Initialization

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(containerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

My view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // UI

    private let baseView = BaseView()

    // Lifecycle

    override func loadView() {
        view = baseView
    }
```

I've also toyed with setting the frame within the instantiation of the `BaseView` to no avail. I've been setting the view, baseView, and containerView to different background colors to verify that nothing displays.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on your `BaseView`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something stupid.